# Google Sheets formula to search multiple rows and columns for value in a cell and if found display value in the cell to the left

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheets form that users will fill out in selecting the type of port on a router they want to build out.

The attached image shows part of the form. The port selections area I want to search is MAIN!A42:H92

On the OPTIONS sheet I have multiple values that are in the dropdown menu OPTIONS!A19:A40. There are 3 specific values I want to search for on the MAIN sheet found on the OPTIONS Sheet.

```
OPTIONS!A30 = NETWORK-INTERFACE-TO-B40-01

OPTIONS!A31 = NETWORK-INTERFACE-TO-B40-01/B40-02

OPTIONS!A32 = NETWORK-INTERFACE-TO-B40-02
```

I tried something like this but it says match can't be used across multiple columns. I've tried find and vlookup as well and not having luck.

From my image example I would have hoped to see the returned value in each cell which I have currently just manually typed for visualization.

For the cell MAIN!H98 I've tried in hopes that it would have returned Port 1/5/8

```
index(MAIN!$B$42:$H$92,MATCH(OPTIONS!A31,MAIN!$B$42:$H$92,1))
```

For the cell MAIN!H100 I've tried in hopes that it would have returned Port 1/4/8

```
index(MAIN!$B$42:$H$92,MATCH(OPTIONS!A30,MAIN!$B$42:$H$92,1))
```

For the cell MAIN!H102 I've tried in hopes that it would have returned Port 1/6/8

```
index(MAIN!$B$42:$H$92,MATCH(OPTIONS!A32,MAIN!$B$42:$H$92,1))
```

I greatly appreciate the support from who ever answers this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: change `,1` in MATCH to `,0`

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach that should retrieve the first match of `NETWORK-INTERFACE-TO-B40-01/B40-02`(aint sure if **NETWORK-INTERFACE...** is unique or present multiple times with the `MAIN!A42:H92` range)*

```js
=+tocol(index(if(MAIN!B42:H92=OPTIONS!A31,MAIN!A42:G92,)),1)
```

Comment: Thank you for that command, it works great!

If 1 instance is matched it gives the results I wanted

If no match is found it gives an error which I just added
'=if(iserror(+tocol(index(if(MAIN!B42:H92=OPTIONS!A31,MAIN!A42:G92,)),1)),"",+tocol(index(if(MAIN!B42:H92=OPTIONS!A31,MAIN!A42:G92,)),1))

I'm not sure if this formula can be updated so that if it finds a 2nd match I can give a pop up error or use an If statement to flag the user they selected a duplicate interface? Thank you again so very much @rockinfreakshow

Comment: As of now the formula design is restricted to populate only the top match (by appending `+` to **tocol**) irrespective of how many matches are found. you can remove it and play around to see on how to deal in a case-scenario of multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try joining ranges on top of one another by the {} approach:

```
={ A:B ; C:D }
```

Then you can combine that with query to return multiple results:

```
=query({ A:B ; C:D }, "select Col1 where Col2='"&cell_value&"'")
```

You can apply the right ranges, cells, etc. But this will be a cleaner approach I feel.